# Render Rails query as JSON for jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a javascript function that takes data from Rails and presents it.

The format it needs:

```
[
  {
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
  },
  {
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
  }
]
```

I'm trying to present this data directly from Rails:

```
<%= raw @bookings.as_json( only: [:title, :start, :end] ).collect{|o| o["booking"]} %>
```

This is pretty close, producing:

```
[{"end"=>nil, "start"=>nil, "title"=>...}, {...}, {...}]
```

All I have left to do now is change each `=>` into `:`.

1. Am I going about this problem the best way?
2. If so, how can I make this final substitution in hash format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `to_json` instead of `as_json`. `as_json` is old syntax and hence may not work.

Comment: I get `[ {"booking":{...}}, {"booking":{...}}, {"booking":{...}} ]`. I need to get rid of the extra "bookings" so it's just `[{...},{...},{...}]`.